# Maximum packet length reached?

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-ec2, tcp, perforce

Clients are having issues connecting to perforce revision server I have set up for them to use.  It appears that they have too many checked out/added files that need to be put into the system and they are getting packet reseet issues.

Specifically the TCP connection is resetting when its trying to communicate with the server.  I made sure the MTU on the eth0 was set to 1492, but I am at a loss on what else could be done to help resolve this problem.

I have csf firewall installed on the server and was searching for any kind of settings that could be tweaked for TCP packet limit but could find no such setting.

Also checked the perforce server logs and this was what I had found: http://www.tinyuploads.com/images/twE0UK.png

Seems like its the packet issue...but i'm not 100% sure.  Running this perforce server on an ec2 micro instance with a SCREEN.

Thanks for any tips/advice, i am happy to provide additional information as requested.

EDIT:  To be more specific this is the issue people are experience: http://kb.perforce.com/article/410/wsaeconnreset-error-description

Comment: What are "packet reset issues" exactly?

Comment: Check edit, posted link to error they are receiving.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by a stateful firewall (or NAT) timing out an idle connection. When the client goes to use the connection, the firewall has forgotten about it, sees the packet as invalid, and sends a reset back to the client.